# How did the shipwright Tom get the blueprints to the Pluton?

Tags: one-piece

In the anime Tom is the best shipwright there is, but how did he get the blue prints to the Pluton. Did he write them himself, and if so how did he get the information needed to do so?

Comment: i think noah is the pluton. because tom was a fishman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Franky explains this, before destroying the blueprints. According to him, the best shipwrights of the world created Pluton to counter the ancient weapon "Poseidon".

I don't think any names have been mentioned, but it is safe to assume that the blueprints were handed down to Tom from his master.

Comment: But I thought that there were three ancient weapons, Pluton, Poseidon, and Uranus? Were they all made in different time periods?

Comment: The idea of Ancient weapons is not clear to me either, since they have joined it with the meramid princess being the weapon "poseidon". There is too much ambiguity. All we know so far that it has to do something with Poneglyphs and the void century. My answer was aimed to answer how Tom got hold of the blueprints. If you want to talk about the weapons themselves, try to ask another question or search for yourselves :)

Comment: Not all of the weapons are "made". While it is true that Pluton is a ship and indeed needs to be created, Poseidon on the other hand is merely the ability to control the Sea Kings. While this is not a tangible weapon, it could still cause mass destruction if the mermaid would have wrong intentions. Not much is known about Uranus though.

Comment: As far as the story goes, the Pluton is a ship created by a shipwright to counter the other Ancient weapon 'Uranus' as told about by Iceburg to Franky during the Enies Lobby Arc in the anime, thus its blueprints were secretely passed down among shipwrights. Not much is known about Uranus itself, except that its shipwright simply wanted to create something really destructive. As for 'Poseidon', she is the mermaid princess who only got the nick name because she has the uncanny ability to control the Sea Kings, thus feared by the World Government.

Answer (score 0):

The blueprints for the ancient weapon [Pluton](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Pluton) were not made by Tom, but passed on to him according to [the Wiki on Ancient Weapons](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Ancient_Weapons):

> While Pluton has yet to appear in the story proper, it has been referred to as an ancient ship capable of massive damage and destruction. It was built on the island of Water 7 sometime during the Void Century, and the shipwrights kept the blueprints as a safety measure, in the event that Pluton fell into the wrong hands; fortunately, the ship was lost to history before that could happen. **The blueprints were passed down through the generations**, and ten years prior to the main storyline were held by the Fishman carpenter, Tom, of Tom's Workers.

Therefore the blueprints were created during the [Void century](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Void_Century) about 800 to 900 years ago and passed down through generations. Tom was the best shipwright of his generation, but when he was younger, there was probably another shipwright as good or maybe even better than Tom, from whom Tom had inherit the blueprints from. The blueprints, could be a real danger for society and should have been destroyed earlier, but as Tom mentioned, it is not the ship that does the wrongdoing, it's its captain. Shipwrights just build the ship. So they kept the blueprints around, to be able to defend themselves, if the original ship ever fell into the wrong hands or to defend themselves against any of the other ancient weapons. In Enies Lobby, Franky destroyed the blueprints, although it is not clear whether he had made a copy or whether he had memorized the blueprints. He is a robot after all. So it might still not be the end of Pluton as we speak.